# RewriteRule does not match as expected (by me)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i cannot understand why this is not working. Maybe somebody can explain it to me.

I have the following:

```
http://www.mydomain.de/my-apache-tag.html
```

which should rewrite to

```
http://www.mydomain.de/tag/my-apache
```

In my .htaccess I enabled this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)-tag\.html$ /tag/$1
```

In my understanding everything between / and before -tag.html should be taken as argument 1.

But the above will lead to a 404. I even put the domain in front of /tag/$1 but this doesn't work too.

Any help is appreciated, thanks much.

Christian

Comment: Try removing the "/" at the beginning of the 'match' part of the rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on apache version, the leading slash is not required. (You can place /? if you want to be able to match both cases) see `@Jeff Parker` comment.

Also, if you want the URL to be displayed as `http://www.mydomain.de/tag/my-apache` in the browser when typing `http://www.mydomain.de/my-apache-tag.html`, you should add the `[R]` flag to redirect.

And of course, your file on the server should be name `my-apache` in the `tag/` directory. Or you will have 404 error.

If you want the client to type `http://www.mydomain.de/tag/my-apache` and be served `http://www.mydomain.de/my-apache-tag.html` your rule is wrong and should be :

```
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)$ /$1-tag.html
```

If you want to combine both behaviour, be careful of loops.